# Is there a way in Windows to check a program's signature is unchanged before every launch?

Tags: windows, code-signing

I am a planning to deploy a program on Windows and I want to make sure it has not been changed once installed.

The program will be signed which I believe could reveal if it had been changed and also confirm who provided the program.

Is there a way to make Windows validate its signature each time it is launched?

Ideally, I am looking for something within Windows that would check for a valid program signature and that the signer had not changed from when installed.